# RPC:S-3 error retrieving information from server

Tags: android, google-play

Many of our users are reporting to us that they cannot download our app as a fresh install or update their app They keep getting this error in google play
RPC:S-3 error retrieving information from server

Note: some of the users can download the app without any problem but it seems that a large part of them(at least 20%) cannot.

Have you encountered this? What should we do? Would uploading a new apk to google help in any way?

Comment: It's a Google Play issue and there's nothing you can do about it. I released a new version for one of my apps this week end and some of my users had the same issue. The issue resolved "itself" for all of them (with or without Google's interference, who knows?).

Comment: We had the same issue with our apps. It happened when Google released new developers tools, but we didn't update ours. Another reason could be that we increased minimal sdk version from 5 to 7. I still not sure what was the actual reason. But the issue was solved when we update our ADT, rebuild apks and upload them again.

I think that all "solutions" in the internet with removing and connecting Gmail accounts, cleaning cache and others just gave some time to developers to update their apk on Google Play. Therefore these manipulations looks like "solutions".

Comment: MistaGreen, it seems weird then that a single user(device) sometimes has this problem and cannot download some times can

Comment: Could this be a App Staged Rollout issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be a play store problem. I have helped people on this a few times. usually it works just to restart the device. Other times I had to delete the existing account and clear all data for play store, then reboot the device.